# Android: Not able to make generic class

Tags: java, android, generics, azure, azure-storage

I've not worked with Generics before. Now it's the time, when I ought to create a generic class, else my code length will become bigger and more difficult to understand.

This is how records are inserted to the database located at Windows Azure:

```
public class Item {
    public int Id;
    public String Text;
}
```

In the same activity where you defined mClient, add the following code:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.Text = "Awesome item";
mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(
        item, 
        new TableOperationCallback<Item>() { 
            public void onCompleted(
                    Item entity,
                    Exception exception, 
                    ServiceFilterResponse response
            ) { 
                if (exception == null) { 
                     // Insert succeeded 
                } else { 
                    // Insert failed 
                } 
            } 
        });
```

I am not able to make generic class for doing operations on database like insertion, deletion,... located at Windows Azure.

This is the link for windows azure reference(if required):

http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/

I tried the following code:

```
public class WindowsAzureOperations<T> {

    T mT;
    MobileServiceClient mClient;
    Context mContext;

    public void insert(MobileServiceClient mClient, T tObject, final Context tmpContext) {

        this.mClient = mClient;
        mT = tObject;
        mContext = tmpContext;

        this.mClient.getTable(mT.getClass()).insert(mT,  // error in this line
                new TableOperationCallback<T>() {

                    public void onCompleted(T entity, Exception exception,
                            ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                        if (exception == null) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

It shows following error:

> The method `insert(capture#1-of ? extends Object, TableOperationCallback<capture#1-of ? extends Object>)` in the type `MobileServiceTable<capture#1-of ? extends Object>` is not applicable for the arguments `(T, new TableOperationCallback<T>(){})`

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with how you're calling [`getTable`](http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html#getTable%28java.lang.Class%29). Given a `Class<T>`, that method will return a `MobileServiceTable<T>`. But `mT.getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends T>`, since the runtime type of `mT` could be `T` *or some type extending* `T`.

As a workaround, have your `insert` method take a parameter of exactly the type `Class<T>`:

```
public void insert(
        MobileServiceClient mClient,
        T tObject,
        Class<T> objectType,
        final Context tmpContext
) {

    this.mClient = mClient;
    mT = tObject;
    mContext = tmpContext;

    this.mClient.getTable(objectType).insert(
            mT,
            new TableOperationCallback<T>() {

                public void onCompleted(T entity, Exception exception,
                        ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                    if (exception == null) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I also recommend you move the assignment of `mClient`, `mT`, and `mContext` to the constructor of `WindowsAzureOperations`. In fact, taking your class at face value, there's no need to instantiate it - just use a static generic method:

```
public final class WindowsAzureOperations {

    // now a utility class so prevent instantiation
    private WindowsAzureOperations() { }

    public static <T> void insert(
            MobileServiceClient mClient,
            T tObject,
            Class<T> objectType,
            final Context tmpContext
    ) {
        mClient.getTable(objectType).insert(
                tObject,
                new TableOperationCallback<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            T entity,
                            Exception exception,
                            ServiceFilterResponse response
                    ) {
                        if (exception == null) {
                            //...
                        }
                        else {
                            //...
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Its not showing any kind of error now. I'll try to run the code and notify you. PS: your experience shows that this is definitely goinng to help me. Once again, Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure sir. Thank you. It really helped me to think in a new way.